# Combining two sorted lists

Tags: python, recursion

I'm just hoping if there's a way to simplify this recursive code that takes 2 sorted lists and combines the two together in a sorted manner (without actually having to re-sort them).

```
def merge (l1,l2):
    if len(l1) == 0 and len(l2) == 0:
        return []
    if len(l1) == 0:
        return l2
    if len(l2) == 0:
        return l1
    if l1[0] <= l2[0]:
        return [l1[0]] + merge(l1[1:], l2)
    if l2[0] <= l1[0]:
        return [l2[0]] + merge(l1, l2[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge):

> `heapq.merge(*iterables)`
>
> Merge multiple sorted inputs into a single sorted output (for example, merge timestamped entries from multiple log files). Returns an iterator over the sorted values.